# Taking the address of a bitfield

Tags: c

I'm going through few C aptitude questions. This one seemed tricky, can any one explain?

```
struct {
    int foo : 4;
} baz;

int *example()
{
    return &baz.foo;
}
```

This is invalid code, but i couldn't figure out the reason.

Comment: If you use bitfield, never use address of (or pointers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foo field is a 4-bit wide bit-field – smaller than a single byte. Pointers can only address whole bytes, so this is invalid. Even if foo was 8 or 32 bits wide (full/aligned bytes on modern architectures) this would still be invalid.

Answer (score 7):

```
int foo : 4;
```

declares `foo` as a bit-field. One must not take the address of a bit-field.

Section 6.5.3.2 starts:

> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates an **object that is not a bit-field** and is not declared with the register storage-class specifier.

So applying the address operator to a bit-field is a constraint violation. (It wouldn't even make much sense, since a bit-field need not start at a byte boundary.)

Answer (score 4):

The colon syntax in the `struct` declares `foo` as a bit-field.

Since a bit-field might be smaller than the architecture's smallest addressable piece of memory (typically the byte on many modern CPU architectures), it's not allowed to take the address of such a member.

Thus, this code fails to compile since it violates that rule.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you compile your file you will have solution:

```
cannot take address of bit-field
```

Because in memory architecture, each time you use pointer it will to take address where it points to. but baz is just a bit field, so it will be invalid.